# User Profile Information in InfoPath 2013 using Claims Based Authentication

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, web-services, user-profile-service, claims-based-auth

When attempting to retrieve User Profile Information within InfoPath 2013 using the User Profile Service Web Service (GetUserProfileByName) under Claims Based Authentication, I am getting the expected username being returned, but the remaining values(First Name, Last Name, Email) are associated with the account running the Secure Store Service ID.

I have been following this blog post to assist with the configuration [User Profile Service with Claims Based Authentication](http://spvee.wordpress.com/2013/04/10/auto-populate-user-information-in-infopath-with-claims-based-authentication-part-1-of-3/)

The rules have been configured as follows: 
[image]

This is the result when trying to create a new item:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jason,

This works for me. The key is that you must set the parameter for the user name before the query runs. It the parameter is empty it will run as the service account. Ensure that your connection does not run by default (this is the checkbox in the wizard that is checked by default). You should run the query by rule after setting the user name.

Recheck Step 24 of Part 2.

Comment: You suggestion was the solution to my frustration